# SFTP/SSH/Filezilla connects from Windows, but not from linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, sftp

I have two networks in neighboring households.
One is 192.168.1.0-191/24 and the other one is 192.168.1.192/26.

Internet <-> (1st) 192.168.1.0-191/24 <-> (2nd) 192.168.1.192/26

Not entirely great, but at least I have managed to limit DHCP in the first network to 192.168.1.0-191 (I do not own it).

My laptop (windows) connects normally to the first network to 192.168.1.56 (sftp server) and retrieves data through Filezila.

My rpi (192.168.1.239) cannot, again through Filezila and throws an error of no route to host.

Here is the error:

```
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command :   open "pi@192.168.1.56" 22
Error   :   No route to host
Error   :   Could not connect to server
```

Given that the packets from my router (192.168.1.193 in the 2nd network -> 192.168.1.50 in the 1st network) are encapsulated (hence why it works from Windows, I suppose), why is not the same happening from linux/rpi from 192.168.1.239? They are both from the same (i.e. 2nd) network. :/

How can I bypass it/configure it?